# Which domain is better among them?

Tags: domains

keyword (Property) + Location(Delhi)

First: keyword**in**Location.com (Example : Property**in**Delhi.com)

Second: keyword**s**inLocation.com (Example : Propert**ies**inDelhi.com)

Third: keywordLocation.com (Example : PropertyDelhi.com)

Fourth: keyword**s**Location.com (Example : PropertiesDelhi.com)

**Here my question are**

> > Which Domain is best among them?
> >
> > Any Effect of Singular and plural keyword?
> >
> > Any effect of Stop words like in,of,the,etc.

Answer (score 2):

*EMD 'Exact Matching Domains' are less effective than ever*

It's no big secret that Google no longer rewards silly amounts of ranking power for exact domain matches and in fact it can actually harm your rankings, especially on new sites. Nowadays unique branding works best because of Google having the ability to associate your site with a fresh unique branding word.

*Stop words*

Google and other major search engines do not value stop words such as 'and, in, the' and will actually count towards 'EMD' which means your more than likely going to get punished for a domain named `cheapwatchesinlondon vs watcheslondon`, also a domain named just `megawatches.com` will rank just as easily as the two previous examples with the correct SEO on page and off page.

*Singular and plural*

A website with or without these can rank just as easily for both without, Google uses many signals and most of these keywords are done off page. For example if people link to your website I brought a awesome watch, then Google will associate your site with watch increasing your website ranking on that keyword, if people use anchors with watches, or link to your website on a watches page externally then that will count towards that keyword...

Using EMD domains VS URLS

Another thing that should be considered is Google is less likely to return the home page of a website than a deeper link. This is because homepages generally are not what people are looking for and Google reacts better with good url names with short domains for example in this case.

`branding.com/properties-in-london` - not only does this tell Google what the page is about it also shows your visitors without being to long and looking spam.. a page `londonproperties.com/cheap-properties-in-london/` looks spammy and repeats itself unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

*Or take them all and pick one maindomain, and make the others alias. But the problem still remains...*

Just do a keywords check. There are plenty sites (like GA) in which you can check the value of a keyword, solo or combined with other words (like your case).

After you find how much a keywords is search, check how many results pop up with the queries. One combination might be searched a lot, but it there are a lot of high ranking sites in the SERP, you might want to check out a less popular, less competitive combination of words.

Comment: Ok....Start by figuring out which version (singular or plural) has the higher search volume. but Now  keywordLocation.com & keywordinLocation.com . Which is better??

Comment: In your example, if you want 'in', you're gonna have to go plural to avoid a weird word "Proper**tyin**Delhi.com", I'd base it on that. But the same research applies. I'd go with +"in", easier to remember (and IMO, plural: propertiesindelhi.com)

Comment: property in delhi=1000 search per month & property delhi =300 search now please tell me  propertyindelhi.com or propertydelhi.com

Comment: @Martijn please 1000>300

Comment: Well, according to my math, 1000 > 300 ;) Check out the first page and see if you can beat them with SEO, if so, go for that :)